# Restore Database from URL (Azure storage) fails without further details

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-storage

On a Windows Azure VM running Windows 2008 R2 and SQL 2012 Enterprise SP1 CU5, I'm trying to restore a backup stored in Azure as a page blob with the new functionality RESTORE DATABASE FROM URL.
So far I've done it several times with backups up to 60GB in size (uncompressed) and it works like a charm.
However, there is a particular backup 32GB in size that I can't restore. It fails with the following error message:

```
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

No further information is provided as to why it fails. If I download the same backup from to the local hard drive I can restore it without problem. I tried executing

```
dbcc traceon(3004,3605,-1)
```

to get more info and I can see that the DB is restored successfully, then it zeroes in the log file and after that completes is when it fails.
There isn't any error message in the SQL logs, neither in Windows Event log.
There is plenty of free space on that hard drive.
VM and storage are in the same datacenter and I've followed all best practices in building the environment.

EDIT> I noticed the following lines in Event viewer AFTER the database is restored and BEFORE it starts restoring the LOG file (in other words, while the log file is being zeroed)

```
SQLVDI: Loc=CVDS::Close. Desc=Open devices!. ErrorCode=(0). Process=2900. Thread=1104. Client. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. VD=Global\https://url/stuff/xx.bak_SQLVDIMemoryName_0.
SQLVDI: Loc=SignalAbort. Desc=Client initiates abort. ErrorCode=(0). Process=2900. Thread=1104. Client. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. VD=Global\https://url/stuff/xx.bak_SQLVDIMemoryName_0. 
SQLVDI: Loc=TriggerAbort. Desc=invoked. ErrorCode=(0). Process=1508. Thread=2008. Server. Instance=MSSQLSERVER. VD=Global\https://url/stuff/xx.bak_SQLVDIMemoryName_0.
```

Is it possible that the connection to Azure storage times out before the zeroing finishes and thus the RESTORE fails? If so, how do I change this timeout?

Comment: I would recommend running the RESTORE while monitoring the server for the [Exception Event Class](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187506.aspx). An exception should occur right before the 3013 is reported. Knowing what that exception is would narrow down the problem significantly.

Comment: If you're brave you can also capture [`exception_ring_buffer_recorded`](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/an-xevent-a-day-20-of-31-mapping-extended-events-to-sql-trace/), or recover it from [`sys.dm_os_ring_buffers`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176083.aspx).

Comment: Ran the RESTORE with the profiler running, with the Exception class marked (all columns). It didn't capture any exception at the time the error occurred.

Comment: Posted as [a **bug** on MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/814595/restore-database-from-url-azure-storage-fails-without-further-details)
**Please vote** if you are having the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to try enabling instant file initialization (it solved the problem for me). To do this you need to grant the SQL service account the 'Perform volume maintenance tasks' permission in security policy.

For instructions, see:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_pfe_blog/archive/2009/12/23/how-and-why-to-enable-instant-file-initialization.aspx

With thanks to this 'question' for providing the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692592/restoring-large-database-backups-from-azure-blob-storage-to-sql-server-2012-in-a

Comment: In my case it is already enabled. Instant file initialization affects only the creation of the database file (MDF) and not the log file (LDF). The log file is **ALWAYS** being zeroed out when created.

Comment: @nulldotzero good point I didn't spot that it was the LDF being zeroed in your case. In my case zeroing the log file doesn't seem to interfere with the backup but zeroing the data file does. In your case the only workaround I can think of is to see if you can shrink the log file on the source database before backing up.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I found an article which describes why the log file is always zeroed:
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/the-curious-case-of-why-the-transaction-log-has-to-be-zero-initialized/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue i found a different workaround.

Rather than creating the backup Log file to store on Azure blob storage, i changed that part of the script generated before execution to store it to local disk.

I'm unsure as to why the log file is not successfully being created when SQL attempts to write it to the blob storage.

Here is a segment of the script in questiona fter my amendmants :-

```
USE [master]
BACKUP LOG [RealTime] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQL14\MSSQL\Backup\YourDb_LogBackup_2015-07-07_09-04-17.bak' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'YourDb_LogBackup_2015-07-07_09-04-17', NOSKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  NORECOVERY ,  STATS = 5
```

Leave the rest of the script generated to RESTORE the database as is.